# An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator in views exposed filters

Tags: 7, views

I am using filter criteria in views for displaying data based on the input selected by the user.
Actually the drop down values in filters are node values of two content types.When I add content to those respective content types the drop down values are updating but in filter criteria configuration the newly added node values are not being checked as shown below diagram

[image]

Even though the above node value is not being checked, the same value is being added to particular drop down as shown below.

[image]

If I check all values individually and manually and check the option **Limit list to selected items** the error not displaying but the problem is when I am adding another node value (for example LOS3) the drop down values are not updating.

I have googled it for this error and I have applied some patches which worked for some of them but no result.

How to overcome this issue?